# Are Stored Procedure failures logged by SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I see a list of stored procedure errors over a given timespan in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Answer (score 5):

You can't, unless the procedure has code to write to the error log, or it results in a certain severity.

Investigate using [`TRY...CATCH` error handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql).   You should be able to capture errors and then write those to the error log.

Answer (score 2):

You can look in sql server logs:

AS stated in MS article:

> View the SQL Server error log to ensure that processes have completed
>   successfully (for example, backup and restore operations, batch
>   commands, or other scripts and processes). This can be helpful to
>   detect any current or potential problem areas, including automatic
>   recovery messages (particularly if an instance of SQL Server has been
>   stopped and restarted), kernel messages, or other server-level error
>   messages.

View the SQL Server error log by using SQL Server Management Studio or any text editor. By default, the error log is located at Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG and ERRORLOG.n files.

If its not at default location, query below to find the location of you're logs:

```
USE master
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Logging SQL Server messages in file', NULL, NULL, N'asc' 
GO
```

Also, recommend to read this article for same: [Simple process to track and log SQL Server stored procedure use](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2003/simple-process-to-track-and-log-sql-server-stored-procedure-use/) and [Easy way to track Stored Procedure errors in MS SQL Server 2008](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363681/Easy-way-to-track-Stored-Procedure-errors-in-MS-SQ)

Comment: Is there is a simple way to wrap my own procedure into other one and track its errors ? For example i call proc1 where proc2 is parameter ?

Comment: It's worth noting the SQL Server Error Log won't record all problems that might occur during the execution of a stored procedure.  For instance, if the stored proc encounters a row containing a null value where the code doesn't handle nulls - that won't be recorded in the Error Log.